# Proving the continuity of a function at a given point - help needed

Tags: real-analysis, functions, numerical-methods, continuity

[image]

I have come across this question and am not sure as to how to go about finishing it. I have started off with working at out the limit at $x=2$ and this is $-4$. How then (or what do I use) to equate the limit at $x=2$ to value of the function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{x^2-4}{2-|x|}=\frac{(x-2)\cdot (x+2)}{2-|x|}$$
So for $x>0$ this is equal to
$$\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{2-x}=-(2+x)=-2-x$$

To check your function is continuous you have to check
wheter 
$$\underset{x<2}{\lim_{x\to 2}}\frac{x^2-4}{2-|x|}=f(2)=-4=
\underset{x>2}{\lim_{x\to 2}} |x-2|-4$$
holds.

Comment: to verify that they equate to each other could I use numerical differentiation? i.e. lim(n tendsto a)f(2+h)

Comment: apologies - please excuse the poor notation

Comment: @Anonaanon why do you want to differentiate? and numerics is not possible for sure, because for the convergence of such things you most time need at least continuous differentiable. Look for example at the direchlet function

Answer (score 1):

Show that the leftand right hand limits at $x=2$ agree with the function value at $x=2$. Once you've done that, you have shown that it is continuous.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your post. How do I go about doing that? Do I have to use a formula?

Comment: Work with the part of the function that is defined for $x < 2$. Show that if you take the limit from the left you get $-4$. Do the same for the part of the function that is defined for $x > 2$.